# How to use Sheets to track a large number of people's progress through large checklists

Tags: database, google-sheets

I hope this question is appropriately specific, but it's a methodology question. I need to use Google Sheets to track the progress of 100 or so people as they work through multiple long skills development checklists. A person may be progressing through one or more of 20 different skills development pathways/checklists at any given time, and each skill might have 100 or more development steps to check off once completed. So 1 person could easily have several hundred "checklist items" to be evaluated on.

So... I need input on the most "proper" road to head down here in solving this with Sheets. Would you track all people's progress in one 30,000-row sheet? If so, how would you practically go about pre-populating the block of 100 relevant rows needed every time a person starts developing a new skill? Can that be done programmatically, or is that unnecessarily complicating it?

I thought about creating a separate checklist template Sheet for each skill, then saving a copy of that template as a separate Sheet for each person who starts developing a new skill. But I quickly realized that was going to create a complicated mess of workbooks in Drive, and working across many files makes aggregate data analysis much harder.

Comment: You are at a planning stage, and it is good to anticipate needs and develop systems. But your question is short on detail of the relevant pathways/checklists. It's not clear whether how much information you want to include for each skill. Moreover, I would imagine that each of the 100 skills could require a different series of information to be retained. Having said that, I would have one sheet per skill; list the employee names vertically (i.e. start in Column A - dropdown from a separate list of all staff and allowance for new staff) and list the skills pathways/checklists horizontally.

Comment: 1) `pre-populating the block of 100 relevant rows`. Since we don't know what the fields would be, it is hard to speculate about this but there may be formulaic and/or script solutions. 2) `But I quickly realized that was going to create a complicated mess of workbooks in Drive`  Use a single Sheets spreadsheet containg 100 sheets/tabs, one for each skill plus sundry sheets for lists of employees and so on. 3) `proof of concept`: whatever you choose to do, take the time to build a "proof of concept" spreadsheet, it will become your template and it will pay off in problem resolution.

Comment: `reporting requirements` You have not addressed reporting; this will be a major issue and will be important to know status by specific employee(s) and/or skill(s). Reporting has a direct influence on design. I think the design outlined above is likely to be suit detailed as well as summary reporting. But, consider reporting BEFORE you design and build the spreadsheet